# Using While loop for getting the handle of rows in a particular Column

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I'm still learning VBA. I'm having a requirement in which I need to work on rows which are not empty in a particular column. I tried `For` loop. But considering 10 thousand entries in the Excel, there were performance issues. Can you suggest a while loop which only jumps to the rows which has value and not through all the rows?

Basically I need the handle of all the rows which are not empty.

Comment: If your are only working on one column, you could store the values of the column in an `Array` and work on the `Array` instead. This normally increases performance quite considerably.

Answer (score 3):

[`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) is your friend here.

If you want all Cells that have Constant Values in them from Column A, then you can use `Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

If you want all Cells that have a Formula in them from Column A, then you can use `Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`

If you want all Cells that are Blank from Column A, then you can use `Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

Together, these 3 will give you *all* cells in the column.  This means that "Non Blank" will be `xlCellTypeConstants` combined with `xlCellTypeFormulas`.  Another name for "combination" is [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union), which lets us stick `Range`s together

```
Dim rngNonBlank AS Range
Set rngNonBlank = Union(Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), _
    Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
Dim rngLoopThrough AS Range
For Each rngLoopThrough In rngNonBlank
    'You can use rngLoopThrough.EntireRow to get the entire Row
Next rngLoopThrough
```